# Recovering from local corruption of SVN software

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am just now being introduced to the world of Java team development at the enterprise level, using Tortoise SVN for version control.  The expert of our group just left on indefinite family leave and may not be back for several weeks.  In the meantime I have messed up the SVN on my local machine (a Windows 7 laptop).

I was having problems diagnosing a bug on this project I was working on, so I decided to simply do an SVN checkout of an earlier version - the latest one known to be working correctly.  But it kept retrieving the current (a.k.a. "HEAD") version, so a coworker told me I needed to delete my folder with all the existing source code in it.  So I did that, created a new folder of the same name, and attempted to set it up to work with SVN.  I was never able to get it working again as a Netbeans plugin, but I was able to do an SVN checkout of the project directly from Windows Explorer.

I was able to edit, build and successfully test the problem project in NetBeans.  Then I attempted to do an an SVN Update followed by an SVN Commit; the commit failed, because I am missing a temp file that SVN was expecting to find [I tried to attach an image, but the system says I need a "at least 10 reputation" to post images(!?)].

Here is the four lines of "error" text displayed on the dialog:
**Error Commit failed (details follow)

Error   Can't open

Error   'C:\Users\larsekj1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MRPDataAccess.svn\tmp\svn-C4246BF8':

Error   The system cannot find the path specified**

![SVN Commit error dialog][1]

Is there any way to recover from this problem?  As always, your feedback is appreciated.

System details:

Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise, SP1 
Tortoise SVN 1.7.12.24070

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at anti-virus.  If you have one running, and can disable it for testing, see if it makes a difference.  That sort of error is often what you see when an anti-virus tool gets in the way.  The tool starts scanning the file which locks it for an instant and causes SVN to not be able to do what it was going to do.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that our Symantec anti-virus software isn't the culprit. My project's .svn folder doesn't even contain a tmp folder, so obviously the SVN "commit" process couldn't find it.  If I knew how to create such a file and store it in that path, I'd do so in a heartbeat! :)

Comment: The tmp folder and files are created on-the-fly while it is processing. They do not live there permanently.